# Disposing of an object that has 2 streams

Tags: c#, stream

The following code is generating a warning. The problem is that we need the pipe to both read and write. How can I safely dispose of the pipe?

> warning : CA2202 : Microsoft.Usage : Object 'pipe' can be disposed more than once in method 'ClientConnection.qaz()'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.: Lines: 465

```
void qaz()
{
    const string THIS_SERVER = ".";
    using (NamedPipeClientStream pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(THIS_SERVER, this.Name,
                                                                   PipeDirection.InOut,
                                                                   PipeOptions.None))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipe))
        {
            string message = sr.ReadLine();
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipe))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("ACK received"); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need Visual Studio Code Analysis to see these warnings (these are not c# compiler warnings).

The problem is that the StreamReader **sr** and the StreamWriter **sw** both Dispose of the object pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You should iMHO ignore the warning and flag it. StreamReader is imho not supposed to dispose the inner stream. It does not own it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing should 'safely' dispose of the pipe. I generally find this compiler warning highly irksome, objects *should* be happy to be disposed multiple times and indeed it is fine to do so for an instance of `NamedPipeClientStream`. I would suggest ignoring this warning here.

For information - the way to overcome this warning is to [write your own try, finally blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) rather than using the `using` construct:

```
NamedPipeClientStream pipe = null;
try 
{
  pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(THIS_SERVER, this.Name, PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None);
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipe))
  {
    string message = sr.ReadLine();
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipe))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("ACK received"); 
    }
  }
  pipe = null;
} 
finally 
{
  if (pipe != null)
  {
    pipe.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Both sr and sw will dispose of the object pipe, so there is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example on MSDN on how to handle this case:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx

It is your pipe that is being disposed of twice, and I don't think this has anything to do with the fact that you're using both StreamReader and StreamWriter.  Or perhaps it does, and you can just extend on the example similarly.